# What triggers the Avenger music change?

Tags: xcom-2

**What triggers the change of music on the Avenger?**

In XCOM 2 (and XCOM 1 as well), the story follows a Three Act formula denoted by a different music track playing during each act while on The Avenger.  The tracks in XCOM 2 are titled *[Stage One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEpVyJ0TzsQ)*, *[Lazarus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcLerJhXXt8)* (for the second stage), and *[Stage Three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uqRUeJpEZk)*.  However, as the differences between the tracks are relatively subtle, it can be difficult to notice exactly when they change.

**What events trigger the switch between acts, and consequently, between music tracks?**

Comment: Just to make sure, XCOM 1 = XCOM Enemy Unknown?

Comment: I'd not come across this. Are these Acts relevant in any other way other than this piece of music?

Comment: @Vemonus Yes, the 2012 game, as per the way the tags are used

Comment: @SouthpawHare I was just checking. It wouldn't have been the first time the games were confused with each other -- I was mostly checking because you said XCOM 1 which wasn't technically the name of the reboot, but XCOM 2 was the title of the sequel. Can't be too careful :)

Comment: @Chris No, it's purely an aesthetic thing in order to break the game up into Three Acts.  Both games in the reboot series do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the modding code, this seems to be the relevant code. **This will contain spoilers!**

---

> Chapter 1 will play until you build the Shadow Chamber
>  Chapter 2 will play from building the Shadow Chamber until killing (I presume) the incomplete avatar during one of your missions
>  Chapter 3 will play from that point forward.

```
function PlayBaseViewMusic()
{
    SetSwitch('StrategyScreen', 'Avenger');

    if( class'XComGameState_HeadquartersXCom'.static.IsObjectiveCompleted('T1_M6_KillAvatar') )
    {
        SetSwitch('HQChapter', 'Chapter03');
    }
    else if( class'XComGameState_HeadquartersXCom'.static.IsObjectiveCompleted('T3_M2_BuildShadowChamber') )
    {
        SetSwitch('HQChapter', 'Chapter02');
    }
    else
    {
        SetSwitch('HQChapter', 'Chapter01');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought it was something along those lines, but that code pretty much spells it out.